# Responsive CSS with older browsers

Tags: css, mobile, cross-browser

I'm making my site more responsive to various devices (tablet/mobile/etc) and I'm wondering if I use the following as a guide for various layout widths if the last stylesheet is a valid cross browser "catch-all", more specifically IE5/6/7. Does anyone know if older browsers will ignore all sheets and include only that last one?

```
<link media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="small.css" type= "text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link media="only screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)" href="medium.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link media="screen and (min-device-width: 1025px)" href="large.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

**OR**

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) { /* CSS */ }
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) { /* CSS */ }
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 1025px) { /* CSS */ }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are thinking of using IE Specific Stylesheets, use **Conditional Comments**.

In your case, it can be done as:

```
<!--[if IE 5]><link media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="small.css" type= "text/css" rel="stylesheet"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 6]><link media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="small.css" type= "text/css" rel="stylesheet"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]><link media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="medium.css" type= "text/css" rel="stylesheet"><![endif]-->
<!--[if GT IE 7]><link media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="large.css" type= "text/css" rel="stylesheet"><![endif]-->
```

If you wanna implement the `@media` queries for older browsers, there are many JavaScript fallbacks for the same.

1. **css3-mediaqueries-js**

   > css3-mediaqueries.js by Wouter van der Graaf is a JavaScript library to make IE 5+, Firefox 1+ and Safari 2 transparently parse, test and apply CSS3 Media Queries. Firefox 3.5+, Opera 7+, Safari 3+ and Chrome already offer native support.

   Get it at [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/).
2. **Adapt.js - Adaptive CSS**

   > Adapt.js is a lightweight (848 bytes minified) JavaScript file that determines which CSS file to load before the browser renders a page. If the browser tilts or resizes, Adapt.js simply checks its width, and serves only the CSS that is needed, when it is needed.

   Get it at [GitHub](https://github.com/nathansmith/adapt/blob/master/assets/js/adapt.js).
3. **Enquire.js – Media Query Callbacks in JavaScript**

   > Enquire.js is a lightweight, pure JavaScript library for handling media queries. It is less than 1kb when GZIP'd and minified, and has absolutely no dependencies. Yup, you read that right - no dependencies, not even jQuery! The most you will have to do is provide a matchMedia polyfill if you wish to support browsers without a native implementation.

   Get it at [GitHub](https://github.com/WickyNilliams/enquire.js).